# Software to assign mouse wheel to keyboard, based upon focus'd window

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to find a piece of software which converts my mouse wheel movement (scrolling) to that of a keyboard command. My research shows AHK does that.

The (minor) complication I have is, I only want this assignment to be enabled for certain programs.

For example, when debugging in Visual Studio, I step through a lot of code by pressing F11. I'd like to be able to scroll to simulate the same functionality (and even click the mouse wheel for step over). However, I naturally don't want this functionality whilst browsing a website.

I guess my question is does AHK do this, if not then what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with AHK. I think it's far the best in this field. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354) shows how you can limit set of macros to work only in particular program – the key is in `#IfWinActive` directive (don't forget appropriate setting of `SetTitleMatchMode` before).